# The proposed key is not within the partition defined by owning publisher:Apache JUDDI and OSB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, osb, uddi, juddi

I am trying to publish Oracle Service Bus proxy services to UDDI registry (JUDDI).
And I am getting $subject when try to publish a proxy service through OSB. Have anyone came across with such before?

Exception is as follows when try to publish a proxy named "foobar"

[2013-05-14 12:53:16,871]  INFO {org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain} -  Application {urn:uddi-org:v3_service}UDDIPublicationService#{urn:uddi-org:v3_service}save_service has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.juddi.v3.error.KeyUnavailableException: The proposed key is not within the partition defined by owning publisher:  uddi:bea.com:servicebus:default:foobar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I definitely have. See this blog post for details

http://apachejuddi.blogspot.com/2013/03/uddi-howto-create-tmodels-with-custom.html

Basically, you need to create a key generator for anything other than a key starting with the default one (which is something like uddi:org.apache.juddi:something)

To more directly answer you, create a tModel partition key generator with the following keys, then retry your operation again.

uddi:bea.com:keygenerator

uddi:bea.com:servicebus:keygenerator

uddi:bea.com:servicebus:default:keygenerator

These are the rules defined the specification.